# CheckedListBox и C#

Tags: c#

На форме есть  `checkedlistbox`  и  `button`,написал код когда выбран строка `checkedlistbox` и нажата на кнопку,то события `button_Click` сделал ту работу чего надо по сути программы,а сейчас вопрос?

Как можно сделать так что бы когда сообщения выводится на `checkedlistbox` если оно не выбрано и не нажато на кнопку то так и осталось на нем пока не будем выбрать и нажать на кнопку?

Кстати сообщение может быть не выбран и несколько дней,и что самое главное сообщение записывается на `checkedlistbox`  при определенных датах(мм,дд,гг).

Нужно сделать так что бы не было дубликатов строк при записи в файл или чтения из файла на  `checkedlistbox`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так понял, что надо сохранять список до тех пор пока элемент не будет выбран.

Вам надо сохранять список в файл. При запуске его читать. Когда вы выбрали элемент, то в событии кнопки `button` либо удаляете этот элемент, либо убираете `checked` у этого элемента.

**Сохраняем список в файл**

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            string sPath = "blabla.txt";

            System.IO.StreamWriter SaveFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(sPath,true);
            foreach (var items in checkedListBox1.Items)
            {
                SaveFile.WriteLine(items.ToString());
            }
            SaveFile.Close();
        }
```

**Загружаем из файла**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sPath = "blabla.txt";

            System.IO.StreamReader ReadFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(sPath);

            string line;

            while ((line = ReadFile.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                checkedListBox1.Items.Add(line);
            }

            ReadFile.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Да все правильно поняли,а пример можете написать?

Comment: спасибо за помощь но есть один момент,при таком случаи в файле сохраняются и повторяющие строки,как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Дубликаты появляются когда вы загружаете из файла? Откуда они берутся?

Comment: Каждый раз в файле сохраняются все что осталось в **checkedListBox** ,одно сообщение может появляться в течении несколько дней,или может в течении дня открытие и закрытие формы произошло несколько раз а не один, и при таком в файле получается дубликаты,нужно что когда загружаем из файла или же загружаем в файл до этого содержание файла удалилось.

Comment: `System.IO.StreamWriter SaveFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(sPath, **false** );`